# Returning a Linked List with recursion when the function takes a single int argument?

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I'm struggling with a function involving Lucas numbers. I need to write a
recursive function that takes a single integer argument n and returns a linked list that contains the first n Lucas numbers. I just need to understand how to recursively return a linked list with only an int argument.

Comment: Typically, what you do in this sort of model is to build upon each return value. You don't need to pass a list around in order to return a list. E.g. after the method recursively invokes itself, you would do something with the returned list, like add more items to it and return the longer list. As you pop back up through the stacks the list grows and grows. The base case would typically return an empty list or a single item list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a helper function.  In pseudo-code:

```
List <- lucas(int n) {
     lucasHelper(new LinkedList(), n);
}

List <- lucasHelper(List list, int n) {
     ...
}
```